# upload image from android to webservice

Tags: android, soap, upload

How can I upload an image file to a webservice using SOAP?

I need it to be used with SoapObejct so the webservice can handle the input file in its context and give it a new filename.

How?
Any code examples?

Yoav

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Convert your image file to a Base64 string and send your string with its name to web-service easily.
Do you still need code sample?

**Edit**

```
public static String fileToBase64(String path) throws IOException {
    byte[] bytes = Utilities.fileToByteArray(path);
    return Base64.encodeBytes(bytes);
}

public static byte[] fileToByteArray(String path) throws IOException {
    File imagefile = new File(path);
    byte[] data = new byte[(int) imagefile.length()];
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(imagefile);
    fis.read(data);
    fis.close();
    return data;
}

public class MyImage  {
public String name;
public String content;
}
```

send your object to the webservice as a JSON string:

in your activity:

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
myClass.name = "a.jpg";
myClass.content = fileToBase64("../../image.jpg");
sendMyObject(myClass);

private void sendMyObject(
        MyImage myImage ) throws Exception {
    // create json string from your object
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String strJson = gson.toJson(myImage);
    //send your json string here
    //...

}
```

In your webservice convert your json string to a real object which is a replica of MyClass.

**edit:**

Also you can ignore Json and have a webserivce method with 2 parameters: `MyWebserviceMethod(string filename, string content);`
pass Base64 string as second parameter.

Comment: OK, how can convert it to Base64?and how to convert back to image file on the server? I found little info for using DataHandler - which is better? A nice short code example will be really great. Thanks

Comment: Is Gson can be used with SoapObject? I am using SoapObject c;... c.adppProperty(...). Should I put the Base^$ info as a property?

Comment: how do you implement your web-service? is it a .Net webservice?

Comment: you send a "string" created by JSON. you don't send "JSON" object.

Comment: **addProperty("paramName",strJson)**

Comment: Which import do I need for the Base64.encodeBytes function???? Or do I need to add a jar?

Comment: How do I decode i back into file? Just decode and write result into a file?

Comment: Thanks, will look in the web for it